# Web Scraping - Unable to determine node or text heading argument to extract data from URL via functoin htlm_node, htlm_nodes/s at package rvest

Tags: html, css, r, web-scraping

Aim to extract three data points from a URL.Able to locate the specific top and individual CSSs nodes and xpaths using selectorGadget. Aim to use html_node function (html(url),CSS)) to extract the elements I am interested at.

Have used the main node CSS (CSS node ._2t2gK1hs") and was able to extract the first element as a string. The top CSS node appears to have embedded only the first element not the other subsequent two although the three elements (one text and the other two numeric elements) share the same CSS node address codes (For all three top "._39sLqIkw" with a heading followed by "._1NHwuRzF")

[![Snapshot of CSS and selector gadget for the specific data points I would like to extract.][1]][1]

In attempting to extract the data I tried:

````
page0_url<-read_html ("https://www.tripadvisor.com/Hotel_Review-g1063979-d1902679-Reviews-Mas_El_Mir
Ripoll_Province_of_Girona_Catalonia.html")
html_node(page0_url, "._2t2gK1hs")``` 

#Resulting in a string with the top element I aim to extract embedded.    

{html_node}
div class="_2t2gK1hs" data-tab="TABS_ABOUT" data-section-signature="about" id="ABOUT_TAB"
[1] <div>\n<div class="_39sLqIkw">PRICE RANGE</div>\n<div class="_1NHwuRzF">€124<!-- --> - <!-- --€222<!-- --> <!-- -->(Based on Average Rates for a Standard Room) ...>

#Failed to extract the two remaining three elements by selecting the individual CSSs or xpaths. 

library(rvest)
page0_url<-read_html ("https://www.tripadvisor.com/Hotel_Review-g1063979-d1902679-Reviews-Mas_El_Mir-Ripoll_Province_of_Girona_Catalonia.html")
html_nodes(xpath = "//*[contains(concat( " ", @class, " " ), concat( " ", "_1NHwuRzF", " " ))]") %>%
html_text(trim = TRUE)```

#Tried passing without success the specific element node followed/preceded by #PRICE RANGE, #LOCATION, #NUMBER OF ROOMS. 
  
#I wonder how should I pass the argument and what node/s to use in the above function.

#Expected result

PRICE RANGE
122 222 
LOCATION
Spain Catalonia Province of Gerona Ripoll
NUMBER OF ROOMS
5

Thank you
````

Comment: Does this get you closer? `html_node(page0_url, "._2t2gK1hs") %>% html_nodes("div div") %>% html_text()`

Comment: Great, thank you, did not know you could combine the two functions. The first calling and extracting the string and the second one sub-setting the string calling the Div individual elements. Thanks again

Answer (score 1):

Those classes look dynamic. Here is a hopefully more robust selector strategy based on the relationship between more stable looking elements, and avoiding using likely dynamic class values:

```
library(rvest)
library(magrittr)

page0_url <- read_html('https://www.tripadvisor.com/Hotel_Review-g1063979-d1902679-Reviews-Mas_El_MirRipoll_Province_of_Girona_Catalonia.html')

data <- page0_url %>% 
  html_nodes('.in-ssr-only [data-tab=TABS_ABOUT] div[class]') %>% 
  html_text()

data
```